# How can I create a form using profiles or form builder that exposes groups?

Tags: profile, forms

I want to make a simple quick add contact form that includes tags and groups. I seem to be able to add everything but groups using profiles. Well I can add groups to a profile but nothing shows up on the actual profile. Then I tried doing the same thing in form builder, but there doesn't seem to be an option for groups and tags.

Any suggestions?

Civi 5.48 - Wordpress

Comment: from memory, the only Groups that would show if you add Groups field to a Profile are the Groups that are set to be Public (logic being profile is used for folk to 'sign up' to mailing lists, hence set your Group to be public to make it available)

Comment: Thats likely it - thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the GDPR extension https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr